# Html image tag inside of the javascript innerHTML tag is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want an image and some text to appear in a `div` by using javascript but have had no luck so far. I tried to use the javascript `innerHTML` property to insert some text and an image but the javascript just breaks.

I tried making the function change the css of the image to appear when it needed to but the `img` tag got wiped from the `div` i was inserting the image into but kept the text.

```
but.onclick = function(){ 
modal.style.display = "block";
wrong.innerHTML = "test";
question1.innerHTML = "sometext.
<img src = "question1.jpg" style = "left:50%; right:50%; top:50%;"/>";}
```

Comment: Apart from having a newline in your string, your nested quotes are also a problem